# How to communicate/word cost ranges?

Tags: ms-project, project-management-style, cost-management

When you display cost estimates, when it comes to ranges, what words do you use to convey: Lower End of the Range, and higher End of the range.

The terms I chose (Min/Max) were not liked , so I was wondering if anyone else had any suggestions. Also, what I consider "min" is actually a reasonable cost and I believe it should cost that much. I'm only putting in the max to avoid potential trouble down the road. So it's really, a TARGET cost and a MAX possible cost. Any help is much appreciated.

Research done: 
I did a lot of research on this and the best article that has the info is [here](https://www.smartsheet.com/ultimate-guide-project-cost-estimating). It recommends saying "best/worst case". Again, management did not like the use of this term either.

Comment: There is no 'best'. The answer in your case depends on your management's emotions and opinions. Did they say *why* they disliked the suggestions? That's where I'd start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessimistic, optimistic.  Favorable, unfavorable.  Conservative, liberal. 
 Plus what you wrote in your OP. I think that's about it.